# Maven plugin: inject project classpath

Tags: java, maven, plugins, classpath

I'm writing a Maven plugin whose job is to delegate to a core module who needs to read files from the project classpath (i.e. the project declaring the plugin as a plugin dependency).

However, from what I understand, Maven plugin comes with its own classpath, thus leading all my `Class#getResourceAsStream` in my core module calls to returning null.

Is there a way to include the project classpath elements in the plugin one?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

OK, the issue was due to a leading slash. Once removed, the following code retrieves the MavenProject instance (you need to add maven-artifact and maven-project to your POM):

```
public static ClassLoader getClassLoader(MavenProject project) throws DependencyResolutionRequiredException, MalformedURLException {
    List<String> classPathElements = compileClassPathElements(project);
    List<URL> classpathElementUrls = new ArrayList<>(classPathElements.size());
    for (String classPathElement : classPathElements) {
        classpathElementUrls.add(new File(classPathElement).toURI().toURL());
    }
    return new URLClassLoader(
        classpathElementUrls.toArray(new URL[classpathElementUrls.size()]),
        Thread.currentThread().getContextClassLoader()
    );
}

private static List<String> compileClassPathElements(MavenProject project) throws DependencyResolutionRequiredException {
    return newArrayList(project.getCompileClasspathElements());
}
```